# Why run tf.global_variables_initializer() multple times does not change the results?

Tags: tensorflow, initialization

In the following example, whether `sess.run(init)` is in the for-loop or not, the results are the same. Could anybody help me understand why this is the case? What does the initialization actually do in tensorflow?

```
==> main.py <==
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in xrange(5):
        x = x + 1
        print(x.eval())

==> main_rep.py <==
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in xrange(5):
        sess.run(init)
        x = x + 1
        print(x.eval())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `sess.run(init)` but is present in this statement,

`x = x + 1`

you are basically creating a new tensor named as `x` which is overwriting your variable `x`. To verify that run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in xrange(5):
        sess.run(init)
        x = x + 1
        print(x.eval())
        print(x)
```

You will be getting an output of:

```
2
Tensor("add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
3
Tensor("add_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
4
Tensor("add_2:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
5
Tensor("add_3:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
6
Tensor("add_4:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

As you can see, a new tensor is getting created everytime. If you really want to ensure your `x` gets the initial value again, you will have to preserve the variable from getting recreated again. One way you can do is by making use of `load` operation. Consider this example:

```
y = tf.Variable(1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in xrange(5):
        sess.run(init)
        y.load(y.eval() + 1)
        print(y.eval())
        print(y)
```

You will get an output of:

```
2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
```